# How do I make the input send a whole word instead of each letter I type after a delay?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

```
search(value) {
   if(value.length > 3) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          searchApiCall();
        }, 2000);
      }
}

 <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg"  
          [(ngModel)]="SName" id="SName" 
          (input)="Search(SName)">
```

Now, this works but problem is that it calls the searchApi for each letter I type. I want it not to do that but a complete word after a delay.

Wants to save number of calls.

Comment: You could save the timoeout = setTimeout(() => { searchApiCall(); }, 2000);
At the beginning of the function call clearTimeout(timeout). So all previous request are cleared and the last one is sent (when input has not changed for 2 seconds)

Comment: people call this "debouncing." try adding "debounce" to your search query and find someone else using this technique in angular. it's popular so you will definitely find something.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [debounceTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime) to delay value change emissions by a set time interval. You could then use [skipWhile](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/skipwhile) to ignore the first N character emissions (for example if you didn't want to search until the user typed at least N characters)

This would look something like:

```
SName.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        skipWhile(v => v.length < 3),
        takeUntil(this.unsubscriber)
      )
      .subscribe(value => (this.debouncedValue = value));
```